# how to use obsolete android sdk versions

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a Motorola Devour phone, which is quite old, and runs android 1.6. I have been trying to write my own apps for it, but I can't run the gradle sync because my `minSdkVersion` is `4`. It comes out with this error:

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 4 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0] C:\Users\mccra\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\animated-vector-drawable-28.0.0.aar\19bf506067f85ca5d48da2fd39d59695\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 4
Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 4,
    or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 14,
    or use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.graphics.drawable" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

I included the tools:overrideLibrary in the android manifest as

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat, android.support.fragment, android.support.graphics.drawable, android.support.coreui, android.support.coreutils, android.support.loader, android.support.v7.viewpager, android.support.coordinatorlayout, android.support.drawerlayout, android.support.slidingpanelayout, android.support.customview, android.support.swiperefreshlayout, android.support.asynclayoutinflater, android.support.compat, androidx.versionedparcelable, android.support.cursoradapter, android.arch.lifecycle, android.support.documentfile, android.support.localbroadcastmanager, android.support.print, android.arch.lifecycle.viewmodel, android.arch.lifecycle.livedata, android.arch.lifecycle.livedata.core, android.arch.core, android.support.interpolator"/>
```

as it gave an error for every single api. When I run the gradle sync, I keep getting the same errors as before I overrode them. Then I tried to change the `minSdkVersion` on each library, but there must be a better way to do this.
Again, I am trying to make this app run on Doughnut, which is `android 1.6, and API 4`.

Comment: *I have been trying to write my own apps for it* -- ..why?

Comment: Because there really isnt anything useful around for 1.6 that I can find.

Comment: Unless you're a time traveller coming from when the only Android phones out there was Android 1.6 there is no reason to develop apps for that version

Comment: you do have a point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get rid of all of those dependencies, as none of them will work on Android 1.6.

Comment: Do you know what I should use instead?

Comment: @GiantNuker: There may not be a single library on the planet that you can use with Android 1.6. You will be limited to the plain Android SDK, without any dependencies.